# Calculate sum sequence by sequence

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table

```
data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2))
```

How can I calculate the sum of a sequences of `n` elements?

Suppose `n=3`, The result of the sequence sum of A should be the column `seq_sum`,

```
data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2),seq_sum=c(1+2+3,2+3+4,3+4+5,4+5+6,5+6+4,6+4+2,4+2,2))
```

How to effectively do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to use `Reduce` and `shift`:

```
dt[, seq_sum := Reduce(`+`, shift(A, 0:2, 0, 'lead'))]
```

which gives:

```
> dt
   A seq_sum
1: 1       6
2: 2       9
3: 3      12
4: 4      15
5: 5      15
6: 6      12
7: 4       6
8: 2       2
```

Full notation with parameter names:

```
dt[, seq_sum := Reduce(`+`, shift(A, n = 0:2, fill = 0, type = 'lead'))]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize there is a `shift` function in R.

Comment: @WCMC `shift` is a function from the `data.table` package; it is comparable with the `lag` and `lead` functions

Answer (score 3):

**Updated based on comments:**

You can also use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
dt <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2))
dt[, seq_sum := rollapply(A, width = 3, FUN = "sum", align = "left", partial = TRUE)]

# > dt
#    A seq_sum
# 1: 1       6
# 2: 2       9
# 3: 3      12
# 4: 4      15
# 5: 5      15
# 6: 6      12
# 7: 4       6
# 8: 2       2
```

Comment: Why is last element 9 instead of 2?

Comment: It seems to me that the last value is wrong. It should be 2 in stead of 9.

Comment: `dt[, seq_sum := rollapply(A, 3, sum,  partial = TRUE, align = "left")]` corrects the result

Answer (score 3):

To avoid repeating summations, a cummulative sum can be stored:

```
n = 3
A2 = c(A, rep_len(0, n - 1))

cs = cumsum(A2)
```

And subtract the respective differences:

```
cs[-seq_len(n - 1)] - c(0, cs[seq_len(length(A2) - n)])
#[1]  6  9 12 15 15 12  6  2
```

Or, equivalently:

```
diff(c(0, cs), n)
#[1]  6  9 12 15 15 12  6  2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2))
n = 3
sapply(1:(length(dt$A)), function(i) {sum(dt$A[i:(min(i+n-1,length(dt$A)))])})      

    # [1]  6  9 12 15 15 12  6  2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(zoo)

dtab <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2))
dtab[, seq_sum := rollapplyr(A, 3, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using `RcppRoll:suml` and some timings for your reference. @Jaap's solution using `data.table` in-built functions is the fastest.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

N <- 1e5
set.seed(0L)
dt <- data.table(A=rnorm(N))
n <- 3

dt_cumsum <- copy(dt)
fun_cumsum <- function() {
    dt_cumsum[, seq_sum := {
        cs <- cumsum(c(A, rep_len(0, n - 1)))
        diff(c(0, cs), n)
    }]
}

dt_Reduce <- copy(dt)
fun_Reduce <- function() {
    dt_Reduce[, seq_sum := Reduce(`+`, shift(A, n = seq_len(n) - 1, fill = 0, type = 'lead'))]
}

library(zoo)
dt_zoo <- copy(dt)
fun_zoo <- function() {
    dt_zoo[, seq_sum := rollapply(A, width = n, FUN = "sum", align = "left", partial = TRUE)]
}

fun_base <- function() {
    sapply(1:(length(dt$A)), function(i) {sum(dt$A[i:(min(i+n-1,length(dt$A)))])}) 
}

library(RcppRoll)
dt_RcppRoll <- copy(dt)
fun_RcppRoll <- function() {
    dt_RcppRoll[, seq_sum:=head(roll_suml(c(A, rep_len(0, n - 1)), n), -(n-1))]
}

ans <- capture.output(microbenchmark(
    fun_cumsum(),
    fun_Reduce(),
    fun_zoo(),
    fun_base(),
    fun_RcppRoll(),
    times=5L))
writeLines(paste("#", ans))

# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#    fun_cumsum()    2.5983    2.6427    2.67526    2.6462    2.7311    2.7580     5
#    fun_Reduce()    1.3903    1.4274    2.84070    1.6620    1.7047    8.0191     5
#       fun_zoo() 1225.1620 1242.9112 1289.76416 1258.1143 1355.1070 1367.5263     5
#      fun_base() 2731.6609 2849.1003 2909.27308 2922.9430 2971.9956 3070.6656     5
#  fun_RcppRoll()    1.7890    1.8430    3.49892    1.9663    2.0774    9.8189     5
```